# How to unserialize PHP Serialized array/variable/class and return suitable object in C#

Tags: c#, php, serialization, cross-language

The goal is to unserialize a [PHP serialized](http://php.net/serialize) string and get sutable object in C#

Is there any way to make this possible in C#(.Net)?

To be more specific:
We need to make an application which comunicates (Via HTTP) to specific website which returns the needed information. Fortunately/unfortunately we dont have permission to website so the data ([array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) mostly) that is returned from website is [PHP serialized](http://php.net/serialize).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose using JSON as an intermediary step could be useful.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Thanks :)

Comment: Fortunately/unfortunately we dont have permission to website so the data (array mostly) that is returned from website is PHP serialized.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably write it to XML or JSON. You can construct your C# object back from the XML

Edit: Looks like there is already a [XML serializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/) for PHP

Comment: Fortunately/unfortunately we dont have permission to website so the data (array mostly) that is returned from website is PHP serialized.