# Parsing returned value from web service in C#

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I am using C# to connect to a web service written in PHP, the issue I am having is how to go about parsing this format that is returned for a few of the calls.

`a:2:{i:0;a:6:{s:5:"label";s:13:"Delivery Date";s:5:"value";s:19:"2010-11-08 00:00:00";s:4:"code";s:13:"delivery_date";s:4:"type";s:4:"date";s:6:"rawval";s:19:"2010-11-08 00:00:00";s:2:"id";s:3:"119";}i:1;a:6:{s:5:"label";s:14:"Enclosure Card";s:5:"value";s:9:"Test card";s:4:"code";s:14:"enclosure_card";s:4:"type";s:8:"textarea";s:6:"rawval";s:9:"Test card";s:2:"id";s:3:"118";}}`

I understand that the above represents an array with various key value pairs inside, but what I am wondering is if the above format has a specific name and if there is a C# parser out there somewhere for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the output from serialize http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php, check out http://developer.yahoo.com/php/phpserial.html

Comment: Also take a look at [How to unserialize PHP Serialized array/variable/class and return sutable object in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914585/how-to-unserialize-php-serialized-array-variable-class-and-return-sutable-object).

Answer (score 0):

I would assume:

a:2 would represent an array with 2 elements.
i:0 would represent an integer (0).
s:5 would represent a string of length 5 and contents "label"

This may be serialized.