# How to convert unserialize php object in .NET C#

Tags: c#, php, .net, serialization, cross-language

I recently got a project which require communication between php and .Net websites.

The developer form php didnt provide much doc about their code, only a client site library and a small piece of sample code.

```
// initialize the form parameters from the data provided in the url
$paramDataLen = (int) $_GET['paramdatalen'];
$paramData = base64_decode($_GET['paramdata']);
$paramData = gzuncompress($paramData, $paramDataLen);
$paramArray = unserialize($paramData);
```

How can i convert code above into C# and use in .NET?

I saw post of this [How to unserialize PHP Serialized array/variable/class and return suitable object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914585/how-to-unserialize-php-serialized-array-variable-class-and-return-sutable-object), 
however since i have no php experience before, would be good if some one can point me a right direction to do this, whith few more details about how a .net guy dealing with php

I am finding a hard time in converting php code into C#
there is another function which i am scraching my head.

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $config['DATAAPISECRETKEY'], $result, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $encryptedData['iv']);
```

is there any equivalent code/lib available in c#?

Comment: You find all PHP functions documented in the PHP manual: http://php.net/docs

Comment: I end up using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914585/how-to-unserialize-php-serialized-array-variable-class-and-return-suitable-objec, and it really worked after a few tweeks.

Comment: D.J. would be cool if you leave some notes in form of an answer how you tweaked / solved it, so you have documented this and others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can transport your object as json.

To facilitate, use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) library.

Comment: thanks for the answer, sending Json out no problem. however since we have no control of the php code neither development. the difficulties for now is how can i consume data from php.