# PHP mysql code help decoding

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, json

I have this value under Items in my DB:

> a:1:{i:0;a:9:{s:12:"model_number";s:10:"TT1-W";s:5:"price";s:4:"3810";s:10:"unit_price";d:3135.6300000000001091393642127513885498046875;s:8:"id_price";d:3810;s:9:"sales_tax";d:290.3700000000000045474735088646411895751953125;s:5:"sales";d:3084.6300000000001091393642127513885498046875;s:7:"service";s:2:"51";s:7:"freight";s:3:"384";s:13:"co_cat";s:3:"X4";}}

Making it more reader-friendly:

```
a:1:
    {
    i:0;
    a:9:
        {
        s:12:"model_number";
        s:10:"TT1-W";
        s:5:"price";
        s:4:"3810";
        s:10:"unit_price";
        d:3135.6300000000001091393642127513885498046875;
        s:8:"id_price";
        d:3810;
        s:9:"sales_tax";
        d:290.3700000000000045474735088646411895751953125;
        s:5:"sales";
        d:3084.6300000000001091393642127513885498046875;
        s:7:"service";
        s:2:"51";
        s:7:"freight";
        s:3:"384";
        s:13:"co_cat";
        s:3:"X4";
        }
    }
```

I am unable to find out how to decode this string since it can not seem to find reference to it in the php code that displays it on the page. It looks to me to be JSON but i can not seem to find a "standard" format for the above in order to start figuring out where it starts and where it ends.

I am needing this to be decoding using ASP.net. But then again, i need to figure out what it is before i can start decoding it!

Any help to what it is would be great!

Comment: Have you tried `json_decode()`?

Comment: @Matt That is not JSON, just similar looking.

Comment: Wait, do you need help with ASP.net or PHP?

Comment: @Matt: I need it decoded for ASP.net. It's currently in PHP.

Comment: Still needing to find out how to decode this using VB.net/ASP.net :o)

Answer (score 2):

Try with unserialize:
   [function.unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php)

EDIT: If you can use C# libraries:
[How to unserialize PHP Serialized array/variable/class and return suitable object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914585/how-to-unserialize-php-serialized-array-variable-class-and-return-suitable-objec)

EDIT2:
[Visual Studio Tip: Three ways to use C# within a VB.NET project](http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/290)

EDIT3:

> i need to figure out what it is

It's standard PHP-solution to store (and restore) arrays and objects (and other types, see manual) in strings.

Comment: Any way to unserialize in ASP.net?

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be PHP's serialization methodology.  You just need to use PHP's `unserialize()` on it.

Comment: Any way to unserialize in ASP.net?

Comment: There may be some library or code snippet available to unserialize PHP in ASP.net, you would just need to Google. I don't work in ASP, so I can't give you any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a serialized object. PHP's [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) is probably what you want:

> `unserialize()` takes a single serialized variable and converts it back
>   into a PHP value.

There is no built in way to turn that into an ASP.Net object, but it is a regular format, so you *can* build your own parser to create a simple dictionary representation of the attributes of that particular structure.

But if you're trying to de-serialize a PHP object in ASP.Net you're probably doing something wrong!

Comment: We are converting an old CMS thats written in PHP over to asp.net so we dont really have a choice. :o)

Comment: Fun times! Ok, well looks like Anton has given you some good tips then. :)